# NoClassDefFound Error while calling Java singleton class in kotlin Class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, singleton

how I'll be able to get data from Singleton class of java in kotlin class.?  since my project is an old project and whole app is in java now I'm implementing its new module in kotlin where I'm using Java's Singleton `(CurrentUser.java)` in  kotlin's Service Class`(UpdateWidgetService.kt)`.while I'm using this `CurrentUser.getInstance().userType` code for getting type of user in My service class its throwing below exception

```
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 27066
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/myapp/main/CurrentUser
```

**Java**

```
   public class CurrentUser {

          String userType = "";

     private static CurrentUser instance;

      public static CurrentUser getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new CurrentUser();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public void setUserType(String userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }

        public String getUserType() {
            return userType ;
        }



    }
```

**Kotlin**

```
CurrentUser.getInstance().userType
```

Answer (score 2):

Rebuild and invalidate cache your project and then restart your android studio. 
Also Sync file system.
I was having the same issue and i did this trick and it worked for me.
Hope this may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In kotlin get userType like this

```
 val userType=CurrentUser.getInstance().userType
```

Comment: I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError for CurrentUser.java class while using it in kotlin class..how I'll be able to get value usertype.? if my class is not been found.?

Comment: Make sure import package is correct path of CurrentUser

Comment: then invalidate caches  android studio and rebuild project

Comment: I tried every possible solution(Clean/Rebuild/Killed process/etc) but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind to provide information if you are using ProGuard for minifying the Code?

If Yes Make sure u add the model class in your proguard-rules.pro file

exmp: -keep class packagename.models.* { *; }

Comment: I'm not using pro-guard.